# I'm using the workbox webpack plugin and in this i'm using the generateSw and i don't want to cache the public folder js files || react

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

```
 plugins.push(
        new WorkboxWebpackPlugin.GenerateSW({
            exclude: [
                /\.html$/,
                // /\/config-env\.js$|\/config\.js$/,
                /\/public\,
                /^(manifest|package|config-env|config|map).*\.js(?:on)?$/,
            ],
            maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 9 * 1024 * 1024,
            clientsClaim: true,
            // skipWaiting: true,
            disableDevLogs: true,
            cleanupOutdatedCaches: true,
            runtimeCaching: [
                {
                    urlPattern: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)$/,
                    handler: "CacheFirst",
                    options: {
                        cacheName: "my-images-cache",
                        expiration: {
                            maxAgeSeconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60, // Cache images for 7 days
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    urlPattern: /\.css$/,
                    handler: "StaleWhileRevalidate",
                    options: {
                        cacheName: "my-css-cache",
                        expiration: {
                            maxAgeSeconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60, // Cache images for 7 days
                        },
                    },
                },

                {
                    urlPattern: /\.js$/, // Match all URLs
                    handler: "NetworkFirst",
                    options: {
                        cacheName: "my-js-cache",
                        expiration: {
                            maxAgeSeconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60, // Cache images for 7 days
                        },
                    },
                },
            ],
        })
```

I don't want to cache the public folder because there are some JS files and CSS files which is not currently minified so I don't want to reveal those in the browser cache. I have a separate folder called minified where I put all minified files(js, css) when I create the build.

And it's also storing the package.json files.

And i also not able to see the my-js-cache in cache folder in browser same thing my-css-cache and my-images-cache

I already used the exclude property in generateSW but files still stores in the browser cache